# Can we set outlineWidth property for polygon drawn using CZML in Cesium?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, czml

I want to reduce the thickness of outline of polygon drawn using CZML in Cesium. I tried to search if there is any option available in CZML to achieve it.

I found [this](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/wiki/CZML-Content), but it provides 'outlineWidth' for label and point.

Is there any way to adjust thickness of outline of polygon?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as smoothly as one might hope.  There is indeed an [`outlineWidth`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/PolygonGraphics.html#outlineWidth) property that can be applied to the polygon in CZML, but unfortunately this simply maps to WebGL's built-in `lineWidth`, which is not guaranteed to support any value beyond 1.0.  In particular, the ANGLE project, which enables WebGL on many Windows-based browsers, has [refused to support line widths greater than 1.0](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/angleproject/issues/detail?id=334) on grounds that the spec doesn't require it.

Cesium does offer a system for [Polylines in CZML](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=CZML%20Polyline.html&label=CZML), and these Polylines use a Cesium-specific implementation of screen-space thick lines that are known to work across all Cesium-supported systems, regardless of ANGLE or max `lineWidth` restrictions.

So the workaround here is to trace around the edges of all your polygons with polylines.  You should be able to get this done automatically in code, and that would give you the thick lines you need.

Comment: I tried to set the 'outlineWidth' as 0.1 (as max possible is 1) and hoped to to see a thinner outline. But it doesn't not work and shows the outline with default width.

Comment: Looks like the minimum is also 1.  Custom lineWidths are not supported in ANGLE, and not required by the WebGL spec.  Using Cesium's polylines are the only workaround I know for this.